# MYSQL, Sum the same row Multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello fellow community,

This is my first time posting i've been looking for an asnwer for days now and i'm a bit starved.

I have a table in mysql that looks like this

```
Package | Speakers | Microphone
1       | 2        | 1
2       | 2        | 1
3       | 4        | 2
```

what i want to do is be able to select any package as many times as i like, sum the totals,and see how much inventory it will take.

Example

Saturday has 3x package 1's and 1x package 3

so in total i will need 10 speakers and 5 microphones

This is my current code in a php file

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(speaker) as Speaker, SUM(microphone)   as Microphone FROM TABLE where package in('".$pk1."', '".$pk2."', '".$pk3."' '".$pk4."')";
```

how can i select multiple times the same row so that it will sum properly

Answer (score 0):

Use multiplication with a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT SUM(speaker * 
            CASE Package
                WHEN 1 THEN 3
                WHEN 3 THEN 1
            END) AS Speaker,
      SUM(microphone *
            CASE Package
                WHEN 1 THEN 3
                WHEN 3 THEN 1
            END) AS Microphone
FROM yourTable
WHERE Package IN (1, 3)
```

Instead of repeating the `CASE` expression, you can instead join with a subquery that returns the quantities.

```
SELECT SUM(t.speaker * q.quantity) AS Speaker, SUM(t.microphone * q.quantity) AS Microphone
FROM yourTable AS t
JOIN (SELECT 1 AS package, 3 AS quantity
      UNION
      SELECT 3 AS package, 1 AS quantity) AS q
ON t.package = q.package
WHERE t.package IN (1, 3)
```

This should be easier to use if you're constructing the query dynamically in PHP.

Comment: I appreciate the help but i may not be as experinced with MYSQL as i thought. I will just have each package repeated 3 times in the database and have each select a different one instead of many of one option. thanks